# Structure of $k[X,Y,X^a/Y^b]$, name for such rings

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials

Rings of the form $k[X,Y,\frac{X^a}{Y^b}]$, where $k$ is a finite field and $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime natural numbers, are showing up as residue rings in a problem I'm studying, and I'm wondering if these have been studied extensively before. The one reference I'm reading in which these appear refers to these as $\frac{a}{b}$-quotient $Y$ polynomials, but I'm not seeing that name show up anywhere else. Are these referred to as something else in other references?

As far as the structure of this ring is concerned, I deduced easily that such a ring is two dimensional Noetherian domain, and it's atomic but not a UFD. Is there anything else to say here? For instance, if I localize at a height one prime Q and get a DVR, is there anything I can say about Q (e.g. a bound on the number of generators and/or what the generators look like)?

Thank you for your attention and help!

Comment: I imagine that these rings might come up in toric geometry, so that could be a place to look (for nomenclature as well as properties).

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn Thanks! I will ask around.

Comment: Another keyword: this is an affine semigroup ring. So, there are combinatorial ways to determine whether it is normal, Cohen-Macaulay, Gorenstein, etc.